# Tukey's symmetrical lambda distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

U ~ Uniform(0,1)

$$Z_\lambda = \frac{U^\lambda-{(1-U)}^\lambda}{\lambda} $$

I have to find the first four moments and two ($\lambda_1,\lambda_2$) such that they have the same four moments.

Comment: What are $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

Comment: The odd moments are zero. What are you going to do with the first 4 moments? And what are the constraints on parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: I have the same question is on Introduction to the Theory of Statistic _Mood Graybill and Boes_1974 chapter III question 30 I appreciate some help.